# Cannot access to folder Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I created a new user in Mac terminal with the command :

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/USERNAME_HERE
```

I want to access to a folder of my principal account when I'm connected with the new account. I change the permission of the folder by doing right click on the folder, get informations, and Share and permissions menu. I add my new user.

However, I cannot access to the folder... I have this error :

```
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
```

Do you know how to solve this error ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You didn't create a new user yet, you just made a new folder. You need to add a lot more info to make a user that works.  I'm sure it would be much simpler to just use the GUI; it's much harder to get it wrong that way, as it will ask you all the right questions. See https://sterlingit.com.au/how-to-create-a-user-or-admin-user-in-osx-apple-mac-via-terminal-commands-in-9-simple-steps/

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your answer. I followed the steps of your tutorials, but I got the same errors ...

Comment: Just do it from the UI, it's a whole lot easier.

Comment: Indeed that's work better from the UI, thanks a lot !